# How to drop a row whose particular column is empty/NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file. I read it:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', sep=',')
data.head()
```

It has output like:

```
id    city    department    sms    category
01    khi      revenue      NaN       0
02    lhr      revenue      good      1
03    lhr      revenue      NaN       0
```

I want to remove all the rows where `sms` column is empty/NaN. What is efficient way to do it?

Comment: I reopen question because OP need the most efficient method.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with parameter `subset` for specify column for check `NaN`s:

```
data = data.dropna(subset=['sms'])
print (data)
   id city department   sms  category
1   2  lhr    revenue  good         1
```

Another solution with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
data = data[data['sms'].notnull()]
print (data)
   id city department   sms  category
1   2  lhr    revenue  good         1
```

Alternative with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print (data.query("sms == sms"))
   id city department   sms  category
1   2  lhr    revenue  good         1
```

**Timings**

```
#[300000 rows x 5 columns]
data = pd.concat([data]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [123]: %timeit (data.dropna(subset=['sms']))
100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop

In [124]: %timeit (data[data['sms'].notnull()])
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop

In [125]: %timeit (data.query("sms == sms"))
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Pls correct me if I am wrong, so the third one is the most efficient way?

Comment: @Danish - hmmm, th best test in your data, but I think dropna. query is slowiest.

Comment: What is the logic behind the equal sign in the query one?

Comment: @Caterina - if check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html) and `In [12]: np.nan == np.nan` `Out[12]: False` it means if compare column `sms` with same column `sms` it generate `False` for missing values and `True` for non missing values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `dropna` for this:

```
data.dropna(axis=0, subset=('sms', ))
```

See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for more details on the parameters.

Of course there are multiple ways to do this, and there are some slight performance differences. Unless performance is critical, I would prefer the use of `dropna()` as it is the most expressive.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = 10000000

# generate dataframe with a few columns
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a_number=np.random.randint(0,1e6,size=i),
    with_nans=np.random.choice([np.nan, 'good', 'bad', 'ok'], size=i),
    letter=np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijklmnop'), size=i))
                 )

# using notebook %%timeit
a = df.dropna(subset=['with_nans'])
#1.29 s ± 112 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# using notebook %%timeit
b = df[~df.with_nans.isnull()]
#890 ms ± 59.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# using notebook %%timeit
c = df.query('with_nans == with_nans')
#1.71 s ± 100 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```