# how to delete wrong row from dataframe when get ValueError by using astype from object to int32

Tags: python, pandas

It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885696/how-to-delete-wrong-row-from-dataframe-when-get-valueerror-by-using-astype), but the solution doesn't solve my problem.

I use pandas's astype function to parse a string into data in `int32` format, but because there are some outliers in the original data, it causes ValueError exception.

I want to delete the wrong row data.

my code is:

```
df['DRIVEDIR'] = df['DRIVEDIR'].astype('int32')
```

the `df` (a small subset) is:

```
                                    DRIVEDIR 
PASSTIME                                                                       
2017-06-02 11:01:08.247000+08:00       3            
2017-06-02 11:00:55.710000+08:00       2            
2017-06-02 11:00:41.139000+08:00       鲁XXX              
2017-06-02 07:43:41.818000+08:00       2            
2017-06-02 11:04:21.317000+08:00       3            
2017-06-02 11:04:18.460000+08:00       2            
2017-06-02 11:04:13.159000+08:00       1
```

I try use `df['DRIVEDIR'] = df['DRIVEDIR'].astype('int32',errors= 'ignore')`, but it can't change the dtype form object to int32， there's no way I can deal with it later.so, how to delete wrong row from dataframe when get ValueError by using astype from object to int32.

Comment: use `pd.to_numeric(df.DRIVEDIR, errors='coerce')`

Comment: Great， the to_numeric should works well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, use `pd.to_numeric`. Invalid items are coerced to `NaN`. You can then just filter them out and cast to `int` after that.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.DRIVEDIR, errors='coerce').dropna().astype(int)

2017-06-02    3
2017-06-02    2
2017-06-02    2
2017-06-02    3
2017-06-02    2
2017-06-02    1
Name: DRIVEDIR, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Because my data is in a dataframe（many columns）, I want to delete the  NaN row from to_numeric, and I use the following code: '    df['DRIVEDIR'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DRIVEDIR'], errors='coerce')
    df = df[df['DRIVEDIR'].notnull()]
    df['DRIVEDIR'] = df['DRIVEDIR'].astype('int32')',  but there is a warning, how to make it no longer warning?:SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @hall `df = df[df['DRIVEDIR'].notnull()].copy()` and this is an unrelated question. If this problem was solved, please mark it accepted. Thank you.