# Drop row if lambda returns None Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
self.df['X'] = self.df['x'].apply(lambda x: my_map.get(x))
```

How can i a drop those rows where `my_map.get(x)` returns `None`.

I am looking for a solution where i do not have to iterate over the column again to drop rows.

Thanks

Comment: Does this means first i ```apply``` and then run ```dropna``` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think it is not possible in one step

Comment: This sounds like you might be better served doing a left join from a dataframe made from mymap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), because is possible remove `None` in first step, by assign to new column create `NaN`s:

```
self.df['X'] = self.df['x'].apply(lambda x: my_map.get(x))
self.df = self.df.dropna('X')
```

Or:

```
self.df = self.df[self.df['X'].notnull()]
```

Comment: I understand this logic, But i am afraid because my one df is 250k rows, and this is a chunk out of 60 million.

Comment: @RaheelKhan - I add another solution, it is a [bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091980/2901002)

Comment: I suspect that if you ask a different question where you share what you are trying to do with the entire dataframe and what your lambda is, you’d get a much better answer

Comment: I tried with 250k df, didn't make any such difference. Thanks

Comment: @piRSquared `my_map` is just a dictionary, where the keys will be `x` i am assigning the value against that key to `X` a new column. But since the data is huge there will be many `x` which will not be matched in my `dict`so i dont want those records in my df.

Comment: Jezrael, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096797/how-to-match-a-word-in-a-datacolumn-with-a-list-of-values-and-applying-ignorecas

Comment: @jezrael Now my other transformation function not working.

`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: Maybe need copy I believe, `self.df[self.df['X'].notnull()].copy()`

Answer (score 3):

Either `loc` or `pd.Series.compress` take a callable argument and return a subset where the callable evaluates to `True`

**`compress`**

```
self.df['x'].compress(lambda x: my_map.get(x) is not None)
```

**`loc`**

```
self.df['x'].loc[lambda x: my_map.get(x) is not None]
```

Comment: So need `self.df = self.df.dropna('X')`

Comment: @jezrael thinking

Comment: can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096797/how-to-match-a-word-in-a-datacolumn-with-a-list-of-values-and-applying-ignorecas

Answer (score 1):

You can find the indices as follows

```
idxs = self.df.index[self.df['X'].isnull()]  # find all indices with None in df.X
```

Full code:

```
self.df['X'] = self.df['x'].apply(lambda x: my_map.get(x))
idxs = self.df.index[self.df['X'].isnull()]  # find all indices with None in df.X
self.df = self.df.drop(idxs)
```

Comment: do you think `self.df = self.df.dropna('X')` this will be more optimized way ?

Comment: `self.df['X'] == None` return False :(

Comment: @jezrael Yes, you're right. You can use .isnull(), but I think `self.df.dropna('X')` is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a merge, if you convert your `mymap` to a dict:

```
mymerge = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mymap, orient = 'index')
```

Then use a left join, to only join on the required columns:

```
mymerge.merge(df, left_index = True, right_on = 'x')
```

In one line:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mymap, orient = 'index').merge(df, left_index = True, right_on = 'x')
```