# How to drop empty rows from a DataFrame when 'pd.notnull' does not work? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have a DataFrame with two columns 'A' and 'B'. My goal is to delete rows where 'B' is empty. Others have recommended to use `df[pd.notnull(df['B'])]`. For example here: [Python: How to drop a row whose particular column is empty/NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091924/python-how-to-drop-a-row-whose-particular-column-is-empty-nan)

However, somehow this does not work in this case. Why not and how to solve this?

```
    A          B
0   Lorema     Ipsuma
1   Corpusa    Dominusa
2   Loremb     
3   Corpusc    Dominusc
4   Loremd     
5   Corpuse    Dominuse
```

This is the desired result:

```
    A          B
0   Lorema     Ipsuma
1   Corpusa    Dominusa
2   Corpusc    Dominusc
3   Corpuse    Dominuse
```

Comment: df.loc[df.ne('').all(1),:]

Comment: You have to understand what values are in your data frames. For example, if it is an empty string, `df[df.B != ""]` would do. If it is `None` or `NA`, then `notnull()` shoud lwork etc

Comment: Hint: try `print(type(df['B'].iloc[2]))` with your dataframe above to see what type you have.

Comment: @jpp: Thanks. I have done that and got: `<class 'str'>`

Comment: So you should try @Wen's solution.. looks like you have empty strings.

Comment: @jpp: Strangely enough, Wen's solution does not work either. It leaves the original DataFrame unaltered.

Comment: @user3483203, I don't think that's true. You can use `df.loc` to drop rows via a Boolean series, no need for `drop`. I suggest OP do some more debugging themselves,  e.g. try `df['B'].iloc[2] == ''`. This is basic debugging which should be learnt when using Python (or any language).

Comment: @user3483203: `df.drop(df.loc[df.eq('').any(1)].index)` leaves the original DataFrame unaltered.

Comment: @twhale You have to check *what* is it in those cells. It could be whitespace(s), tabs, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could have whitespaces, tabs or even a `\n` in these blank cells.

For all those cases, you can `strip` values first, and then remove the rows, i.e.

```
df[df.B.str.strip().ne("") & df.B.notnull()]
```

I believe this should cover all cases.

Comment: The empty cells are cells that have never been filled after the column was created. This solution does not yet do the trick. Would it be possible to fill those cells with something (e.g. '0') and then drop?

Comment: Can you post how you are creating this data frame? If a csv file, how you post a sample csv?

Comment: My function is complicated. But it either returns a string to the cell or it returns a white space ''. (So I expected your solution to work.) And then writes the result to a csv file.

Comment: Following jpps' suggestion, what does `df['B'].iloc[2] == ''` print ?

Comment: It prints `False`.

Comment: Awesome. So do it untill you find out what the hell is in that cell :) (i.e. until something returns `True`)